# show file name for grep match

Tags: linux, grep

I am using cat to display content for a file files and grep for a string, for example, `cat log/* | grep 'error'`, and wondering if there is an option to show which file name matched "error" under folder log? The current command I am using above only show matched lines.

Using Linux.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: try `grep 'error' log/*`

Comment: Maybe I don't get you.`ls log/ | grep error `

Comment: Are you trying to find `error` as part of the **name** of a file or in the **contents** of a file? Show some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` itself receives file arguments. so

```
grep 'error' log/*
```

would work.

additionally, coloring and line number are preferred to show:

```
grep -n --color 'error' log/*
```

it's so common to use, you can put following in your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias grep='grep -n --color'
```

but it doesn't work in script so make sure you understand what `alias` actually is.

---

## UPDATE

and it seems i misunderstood your question. so actually what you want is this:

```
ls log/*error*
```

I don't know what you try to do, but if you try to use names returned by `ls`, that's a wrong thing to do. it depends on your language, in `bash`, you should use globbing to loop over file names:

```
for file in log/*error*; do
    do-your-stuff $file
done
```

in other languages, you should have better tools other than calling an extra process.

about why `ls` is bad:　http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: works for me for local files. For remote files (e.g. files on Hadoop), I am using command hadoop fs -text log/* | grep -n --color 'error', and I tried for remote file, file name on HDFS is not displayed, is there a way to show matched file name on HDFS? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa i didn't encounter HDFS before. is it mounted in your machine? for example, could you use `cd` to get in?

Comment: @LinMa i assume your command `hadoop fs -text` shall return a list of file names, but there is a basic problem in your command, you should use `hadoop fs -text 'log/*'`, watch the quotes. otherwise, your `*` won't even get in `hadoop` binary. but i would suggest to use absolute path to dis-ambiguous things.

Comment: thanks for the help. For your first line of the loop, "for file in log/*error*", shall it be the "ls log/*error*" command result other than refer the files directly? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa no, mine is correct. it's [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html). have a read the link i showed a few lines lower. it explains you why you don't want to use `ls`.

Comment: tried glob and it works. But not sure how it related to my question. I want to scan all files under sub-directory log, and if the file content contains string "error", I want to show the file name.

Comment: This is what I tried, and it seems the file name (for files which contains error) is not shown,

for file in *.py; do
    grep -n --color 'error' $file
done

Comment: @LinMa you'd better to post a new question and have a serious read on the bash books. you missed a `;` after `$file` in the first place. then you are searching `*.py` files in your working directory. are you sure there are any? and again, `grep` receives params, so `grep error *.py` will work.

Comment: BTW, this is my new script, still no file name showed. for file in *.py;
do grep -n --color 'main' $file;
done

Comment: @LinMa then it just simply tells you you don't have python file locally with `main` in any place of its content. I don't have your system and can't even have a check so it really relies on yourself to figure out what's going on in your system.